# Traveling salesman (TSP): what is the Relation with number of vertices and length of the found route?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, graph-theory, combinatorics

I know that there are many algorithms (exact or approximate) which implement the traveling salesman problem.

I would like to know the relation between the number of the vertices (i.e., the places to visit) and the length of the route found by these algorithms.

Intuitively, the less the number of the vertices, the shorter the route is. But, can any one give me the math relation between the number of the vertices and the length of the route found by at least one of the existing traveling salesman algorithms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to solve it yourself? atleast have a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

In general given `n` nodes, let the set of costs be defined as `C = { c(i, j) = cost to traverse edge from node n(i) to n(j) :  0 ≤ i, j < n and i, j are integers}`.

A naive bounding of the closed circuit path total distance will be bounded below by `n*min(C)` and above by `n*max(C)` where `min(C)` is the minimum cost to traverse an edge between two nodes, and `max(C)` is the maximum cost to traverse an edge between two nodes.

If looking for the shortest path not in a circuit then this becomes `(n-1)*min(C)` and `(n-1)*max(C)` respectively.

Beyond that, there are a variety of methods for getting [better upper bounds](https://www.google.com/search?q=traveling+salesman+problem+upper+bound) and [better lower bounds](https://www.google.com/search?q=traveling+salesman+problem+lower+bound).

Comment: Better upper bounds for the TSP are possible.  For example, you could find a minimum-weight matching to get RoundDown(n/2) of the edges, and then upper-bound each of the remaining RoundUp(n/2) edges with max(C) as before.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah, I shouldn't have been so hasty in my original response.  I've edited to at least partially address your comment.